# Unable to start postgresql service in Redhat linux 7

Tags: postgresql, rhel

I have installed postgresql 9.4 on Redhat 7 server.It was installed through postgresql-9.4.3-1-linux-x64.run. It displayed a clear message"postgres is installed your machine". Now when I login as

```
su - postgres
```

It doesn't ask for password and goes to bash prompt. If I type `psql` displays "command not found". When I tried starting service through root user

```
service postgresql initdb
```

I get:

> The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl.

I tried `start postgres restart` which didn't work. I tried searching and found nothing. I know its with starting service.

Comment: post this question in ubuntu section.

Comment: `initdb` does not "start" postgres, To start a service you need to use `start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**service postgresql initdb**

[initdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-initdb.html) is an independent command to create a new database cluster.

> initdb -- create a new PostgreSQL database cluster
>
> `initdb [option...] [--pgdata | -D] directory`

You must use it independent, but not as argument for `service` command. Read documentation how to use this command: [initdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-initdb.html)

Use `service postgresql start` to start postgresql service and `service postgresql stop` to stop it.

**psql: "command not found"**

Try to switch into `postgres` user using `su postgres` command (without dash). It effects on `$PATH` environment variable.If this wouldn't help use full path to specify the command, for example `/usr/bin/psql`